# Does anyone have any experience of removing iFolder from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I have iFolder server running on my ubuntu server and would like to remove it. I can find the instructions for installing but not how to remove. Has anyone done this before and can give me some pointers?

Thanks

Neil

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @AndrewM. using the instructions I posted a link to below... Repeated here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/adedb8f5-271e-4878-825d-83ea87a02be7/6d9b9e7fff0e2765000bd3b4356cc762

Answer (score 1):

Post the instructions you used to install the software. From a quick google search I conclude you probably build the deb and installed it. In that case you can try:

```
apt-get remove simias-server
```

Comment: I will have used the instructions from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iFolderInstall

Comment: Actually I now realise that's not true I used these: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/adedb8f5-271e-4878-825d-83ea87a02be7/6d9b9e7fff0e2765000bd3b4356cc762

Comment: So I went ahead and tried to remove using the suggested command but I get E: Couldn't find package simias-server. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
# apt-get remove ifolder* libflaim* log4net*
```

or something like that?
then to remove all of the data and files related to the ifolder syncs

```
# rm -rf /var/simias
```

thats the default location

```
find / -name "simias"
```

should tell you where it is if it's not in the default. the */simias/data folder is where all the files that have been syncd reside as well as the config

best,
daniel from nofolder.com

Comment: Hi Daniel - that brings back "E: Couldn't find package ifolder*" but the folder /var/simias does exist so is definitely installed. Could it be called anything else? Thanks Neil

Answer (score 0):

williamsdb,

try dpkg -l and look for anything with ifolder or simias then you should be able to apt-get remove that package. it's been a while since i've been on ubuntu but i hope this helps.

can you start a topic at www.nofolder.com maybe? i think it would help the community.

best,
daniel from nofolder.com